# Haskell: finite types of user-defined values?

Tags: haskell, types

Part of the power of Haskell is delegating range checks to the type system (see for example Numeric.Natural). Is this possible to do for types whose set of values is defined once at runtime? I'd effectively like an Enum whose values are unknown at compile-time.

Edit: In terms of example usage:

```
-- Defines the list of allowed values
init :: [a] -> ?

-- Constructs a new instance
construct :: a -> ? -> Maybe Foo

-- Then just usable like an enum
bar :: Int -> Foo -> Bar
```

Ideally I'd be able to use things like `Bounded` on it too.

Comment: well types are erased at runtime (can you give an example - because isn't what you are asking just some kind of `isElem value set` where `set` is defined at runtime?)

Comment: This is basically the problem I'm having. I thought it might be possible to have some internal representation as ([allowed], Maybe value) but it doesn't have very nice semantics.

Comment: Can you show some imaginary code using this hypothetical feature? Are you talking about something like dependent types?

Comment: As much as I love Haskell, I'd not say it can effectively handle static range checks. E.g. array index runtime checks are still needed (or unsafely avoided, when performance really matters).

Comment: @chi: at least for the example of array indices, I'd say Haskell does a pretty good job of doing “static range checks” – by consequenty eschewing indices from being used in the first place!

Comment: @leftaroundabout True, yet sometimes random access is really needed. Actually, I'd say that if you are using arrays without needing random access, you are doing it wrong. :)

Comment: @chi: well, if you only need operations that would have the same complexity on lists, it can still make sense to use arrays instead for performance. But you're right – realising that I need random access is what usually prompts me to switch from lists to arrays (though `IntMap` can occasionally be a better choice). My point was that indices are far less often needed in Haskell than in most other languages, even less than in R or Matlab etc. which also advertise heavily the avoidance of indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code is, unfortunately, too sparse to indicate what you really mean. I'm guessing you may be after dependent types, as [n.m. suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485939/haskell-finite-types-of-user-defined-values#comment64373932_38485939). If that is the case, you're likely better off looking at something like Agda instead of Haskell. If you want a somewhat safer version of what [Daniel Wagner suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38487438/1477667), you can get it with the [reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

module DynEnum (.... not including newtype constructors) where

import Data.Reflection
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Set (Set, splitMember, size, lookupIndex, fromList, elemAt, member, findMin, findMax)
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Bool
import Data.Type.Coercion

-- Just Enum
newtype Limited a s = Limited { unLimited :: a }

type role Limited representational nominal

-- We can safely conflate types of values that come
-- from the same set.
coerceLimited :: (Reifies s (Set a), Reifies t (Set a), Ord a)
              => Maybe (Coercion (Limited a s) (Limited a t))
coerceLimited
  | reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s) == reflect (Proxy :: Proxy t)
      = Just Coercion
  | otherwise = Nothing

instance (Ord a, Reifies s (Set a)) => Enum (Limited a s) where
  toEnum i
    | 0 <= i && i < size values = Limited $ elemAt i values
    | otherwise = error "Limited toEnum: out of range"
    where values = reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)
  fromEnum x = case lookupIndex (unLimited x) (reflect x) of
                 Nothing -> error "Limited fromEnum: out of range"
                 Just i -> i
  enumFrom (Limited a) = case splitMember a (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)) of
                 (_, False, s) -> fmap Limited $ toList s
                 (_, True, s) -> Limited a : fmap Limited (toList s)
  enumFromTo (Limited a) (Limited b) = case splitMember a (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)) of
                 (_, inclFirst, s) -> case splitMember b s of
                   (t, inclLast, _) -> bool id (Limited a:) inclFirst
                                        . (map Limited (toList t) ++)
                                        $ bool [] [Limited b] inclLast

initialize :: Ord a
           => [a]
           -> (forall s . Enum (Limited a s) => Proxy s -> r)
           -> r
initialize vals f = reify (fromList vals) f

construct :: forall s a . (Ord a, Reifies s (Set a)) => a -> Maybe (Limited a s)
construct x
  | x `member` reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s) = Just (Limited x)
  | otherwise = Nothing

newtype Bound a b = Bound a deriving (Enum)

type role Bound representational nominal

instance Reifies b (a, a) => Bounded (Bound a b) where
  minBound = Bound . fst $ reflect (Proxy :: Proxy b)
  maxBound = Bound . snd $ reflect (Proxy :: Proxy b)

initializeBounded :: (a, a)
                  -> (forall b . Bounded (Bound a b) => Proxy b -> r)
                  -> r
initializeBounded bounds f = reify bounds f

newtype LimitedB a s b = LimitedB (Bound (Limited a s) b)

deriving instance (Ord a, Reifies s (Set a)) => Enum (LimitedB a s b)
deriving instance Reifies b (Limited a s, Limited a s) => Bounded (LimitedB a s b)

initializeLimitedB :: Ord a
                   => [a]
                   -> (forall s b . (Enum (LimitedB a s b), Bounded (LimitedB a s b)) => Proxy s -> Proxy b -> r)
                   -> r
initializeLimitedB [] _f = error "Cannot initialize LimitedB with an empty list"
initializeLimitedB vals f = reify set $ \ps ->
                     reify (Limited (findMin set), Limited (findMax set)) $ \pb ->
                     f ps pb
  where
    set = fromList vals
```

Comment: Sorry for the sparsity; I'm finding it a difficult concept to express. After a quick Google, it seems that I do want dependent types. In this case, ones whose set of values depend on something defined at runtime. I'm going to accept your answer however as I believe it's the closest I can get to my goal in Haskell. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @TomJohnson, you may well be able to do what you want in Haskell with singletons; it'll just be rather ugly and likely inefficient. The trick there is to come up with a type-level representation of a set of values, and then use a GADT to bring that down to the term level. Take a look at [Data.Type.Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level-sets-0.7/docs/Data-Type-Set.html) in the `type-level-sets` package for a relatively simple (but still quite tricky!) example.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a `Set` is suitable for your needs. We have:

```
initialize :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a
initialize = fromList

construct :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Maybe a
construct x xs = guard (x `member` xs) >> return x

dynamicMinBound :: Set a -> Maybe a
dynamicMinBound xs = fst <$> minView xs

dynamicMaxBound :: Set a -> Maybe a
dynamicMaxBound xs = fst <$> maxView xs

enumerate :: Set a -> [a]
enumerate = toList

dynamicToEnum :: Int -> Set a -> Maybe a
dynamicToEnum n xs = guard (inRange n (0, size xs-1)) >> return (elemAt n xs)

dynamicFromEnum :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Maybe Int
dynamicFromEnum = lookupIndex
```

I believe this covers the operations you asked for, though I could easily have misunderstood something -- your specification is not 100% clear to me.